# How to join two varchar2 datatypes columns in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I join `xla_ae_lines.description` with `ap_invoice_distributions_all.description`?

Every time I used this syntax

`xla_ae_lines.description = ap_invoice_distributions_all.description`

I got no rows selected. They are both in `varchar2` datatypes in Oracle 11g. So, what would be the right syntax for this?

Comment: Could you include data from both tables ?

Comment: @RallyCautiverio. Yes. also include schema of both tables. So we can help you with your problem.

Comment: The syntax is correct. Most probably the values don't match. Are you aware that Oracle's character comparison is case sensitive? `'FOO'` is a different value than `'foo'`.

Comment: The values of both tables are the same - which includes the case sensitivity of all values. They have both values in each column and both values are the same when it comes to case sensitivity. What I mean is that the other column value has: 'Check Payroll' and the other column value has: 'Check Payroll' and I used the above stated syntax with no rows returned. How can it be???

Comment: Include data and table structure please

Comment: In that case include the sample data and the full query you are using. Ideally create an example on http://sqlfiddle.com to show your problem.

Comment: do you have some filters?

Comment: a stupid one: `trim(xla_ae_lines.description) = trim(ap_invoice_distributions_all.description)` ...?

Comment: @david a. : The syntax you gave me as shown above is really fantastic... That is the answer that I am looking for... It is really great... I have tested it and found the result that I am looking for... You're the man!!! Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 0):

Reposting from my comment above:

[Trim](http://docs.oracle.com/html/A95915_01/sqfunc.htm#i1007071) away trailing and leading blanks from both varchars before comparing them:

`trim(xla_ae_lines.description) = trim(ap_invoice_distributions_all.description)`

Even better, if leading/trailing blank characters are not expected, consider trimming them when **inserting** the data to your tables.